# Redirect multiple domains to one url

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

Using .htaccess, I need to redirect two domains to a third url for a client.
Redirecting one to another works without any issues:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =domain1.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.domain1.com [OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But if I take the same approach for multiple domains I end up with a redirect loop -

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =domain1.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.domain1.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =domain2.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.domain2.com [OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain3.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

How should I set this up in order for it to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because last rule matches everything even for domain3. You should cut redirects for it by the condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www.)?domain1.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www.)?domain2.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(www.)?domain3.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain3.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Ok. I tried your code and it doesn't seem to apply any rewrites. Maybe you missed something?

Comment: That did it, thanks! Think I got a grasp of how the routing works now.